# MS Excel Compare 2 Columns And Add Additional Column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

really need some professional ms excel guru, I'm working in small company HR and we have a list of names of our clients and employees (3000 names give or take) with their salary by the side,

now our management wants to add like say "bonuses" to the salary but don't want to add it directly to it's cell but a column next to the "salary's" column,

I've drawn a chart of basically what I'm talking about, I know it's doable or any way of comparing a list of our employee's name and adding additional columns to the employee's row?

[Example Of Workflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4jfM.png)

Comment: So a company with 3000+ employees and customers cannot hire a developer for this kind of tasks :(

Answer (score 0):

Create a named range by the name of "BonusList", anywhere in the same workbook as the list of salaries. That list should consist of 2 columns, the first of which has the names, the second the bonus.

Use this formula in the column where you want the bonus to appear (the new column).

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A3, BonusList,2,FALSE),"")
```

Make sure that the names are in column A of the salary list. You can change the column, if the names are in another column. Make sure that the row in which you paste the first formula is aligned with the row in the formula (here it is row 3). Copy down.

The formula will display a blank if the name from the salary list isn't found in the bonus list.

Comment: Dear sir, after some further studying of "named range" and some tweaking of your code, you made my day! you have my thanks! Thanks You VERY MUCH!

Comment: If an answer fit your needs, please mark it as accepted. That's the way we say "thank you" in this site.